# Veracrypt message "write protected volume"

Tags: disk-encryption, storage, veracrypt, disk-image

I created a hidden volume in Veracrypt. I didn't select the option for my volume to be write-protected but when I try to copy files to the volume, I get a message "saying this disk is write-protected." How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When you mount the volume in Veracrypt, ensure that the "Mount as read-only" option in unchecked. To see this option, you need to first click on "Options" :
[image: Veracrypt mount window]